# Maximum simultaneous HttpRequests in IIS7

Tags: c#, multithreading, iis-7, httprequest

I wrote multithreaded application in Asp.Net that is doing alot of HttpRequests and sometimes it seems to me that if a lot of threads are doing Http requets at same time, I get more errors then usual.I was wondering if there is any default limit to number of connections at once since I am hosting this application at paid host, and also was wondering if there is any limit to this, are the other threads that are trying to send request failing because of limit being exceeded or is there any internal system that handle connction ie. puts them off until connection is available.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you should reconsider queuing http request from the client side or having a limited parallel requests ?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the `DefaultConnectionLimit` by address in the web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="80"/>
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

You also should check the timeout for the web requests. What is the exception generated?

Comment: I am doing a lot of requests so there are many errors like when site expired,unavailble,timeout etc. This is acceptable, Im just tying to make sure errors are not generated by connection limit. Im not sure if HttpRequest class uses Sockets but if it is then I should get exception with message like this: "An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full." when Maximum parallel connections have reach it's limit, correct?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, HTTP 1.1 server is limited to two connection wherein 1.0 server is limited to four connections. Therefore you can check how many outstanding/in process requests to an HTTP/1.1/1.0 server that you send from your asp.net app.

This can declaratively  altered through `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` = 5; ( eg: 5 outstanding connections)

In addition, you also mentioned it's a paid host. If that is the case, it’s worth checking your request limit (if any) with the provider.

Comment: I tried altering DefaultConnectionLimit but it has some sort of protection agianst changing.I will check what is the limit with my host but I am curious what happens to conection if you call it and limit is already full?Do you just get an exception or does it go pending until connection slot opens?

Comment: And how do you mean "server is limited"? I'm on shared server with many other people, wouldn't that mean that if I use 2-4 connections at same time no one else would be able to use them? Please explain